# Ghost box displayed in the notification area

Tags: customization

I have a problem with this in the notification area. Apparently a "ghost box" is below these options, so that not all look good, especially the volume bar. Thanks in advance for your reply.

This is the "ghost box":

[image: pic]

And this is the volume bar:

[image: pic]

Comment: looks like the theme you are using has bugs in it.

Comment: I do not know. When I installed GNOME in Ubuntu me that weird box appears on the installed themes, as NUMIX or MBuntu, this excludes Ambiance and Radiance themes (sorry for my English, I only speak and write in Spanish and I'm using a translator)